# CentOS 7.2 will not halt on Hyper-V 2012 R2 Core

Tags: centos, hyper-v

I've just installed a fresh CentOS VM on Hyper-V 2012 R2 Core and when I `halt` the VM the machine doesn't get powered off. I installed [LIS 4.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51612) and rebooted, but I still get the same behaviour. Any ideas on what's up?

**Versions**

- CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
- Hyper-V 2012 R2 Core

**EDIT**

I also have  CentOS 6.8 guest running on the same Hyper-V host and that halts fine and powers off no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `acpid` daemon is up and running (in the guest OS).

You can do that issuing the following commands: `yum install -y acpid; systemctl enable acpid, systemctl restart acpid`

Than try to poweroff.

Comment: No joy. I did this after rebooting. `systemctl | grep acpid` and get `acpid.service  loaded active running   ACPI Event Daemon`